# Firebase basic rules issues

Tags: javascript, firebase, security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase realtime database that stores users information. I am creating a dashboard where I can track all of this , but I am having trouble with creating secure rules. I want to be able to read and write on this dashboard but users cannot read the database. I will be the only person on the dashboard since its local. I was thinking of like checking for an api key that I can have in the dashboard but I cannot find any information online. If you have any suggestions please let me know. These are my current rules below. I have it to where nobody can read the database but they can write to it. I want to be able to read the database from the dashboard.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "false",
    ".write": true,
     "posts": {
            "$uid": {
        ".write": "!data.exists()"
 }
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The security rules will depend on what exactly it is that the users can read/write but if you wanted to be the only person who can do either you could set the security rules to something like,

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$node_with_data": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === 'enter_your_uid_here_123' ",
        ".read": "auth.uid === 'enter_your_uid_here_123' "
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This means that the only person who can read/write to the node specified is the the user with the uid that matches the one you enter. Obviously this would mean the users couldn't write to this node so you'll need to think about what types of users you have and what they're allowed to access.

Here's a useful link [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth#realtime-database)

Comment: Yea, what I did is use firebase Authentication and what I can do is allow only authenticated users through since I don't authenticate anyone or I can only let my gmail through which works great!

Answer (score 0):

What I did is use firebase Authentication and what I can do is allow only authenticated users through since I don't authenticate anyone or I can only let my Gmail through which works great! Mine looks like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.token.email_verified == true && auth.token.email.matches(/YOUROWNEMAIL/)",
    ".write": true,
     "posts": {
            "$uid": {
        ".write": "!data.exists()" // This makes it so nobody can delete anything
 }
 }
}
}
```